# Plugin "Android Bundle Support" is incompatible

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-bundle

everyone, I have a very weird error when i launch android studio since last update. I have this error:

*Plugin Error: Plugin "Android Bundle Support" is incompatible (until build AI-195.SNAPSHOT < AI-201.8743.12).*

I can't find any info online about it. When i paste on google just like i did here. No results are found. Could you please tell how i could fix it ?
Sorry about not giving anymore details but there is very few info online.
Thank you so much in advance ;)

Comment: What is your updated android-studio version?

Comment: I am in android studio 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Android Support plugins and libraries have been deprecated now. You will have to migrate to AndroidX from Android Support.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate_an_existing_project_using_android_studio

Comment: The weird thing is that i migrate to androidx several months ago and it's just now i have this message. It apparently came with the update to android 4.1 or 4.0.

Comment: Seems u hv been using this plug-in in your project. Search for it and then delete it or else migrate it.

Comment: Can i safely delete it if i already migrated to androidx?

Comment: @PrajwalWaingankar which line to delete?

Answer (score 0):

i finally find the answer. Just as Prajwal said, by disabling it it should no longer be a problem if you migrated to androidx. I disabled it and it never appeared again. I am sure it is just an an unused bundle support. That's at least the best explanation i have. If i am wrong, please let me know.
Thanks to all that helped me in this question,
Federico